# Loop through gridview and look if todays date is between the ones spesified in gridview

Tags: vb.net, date, gridview, datagridview

I have a grid view with columns (year(checkbox))(Start),(End). I want to loop through the gridview and see between which end and start date todays date falls and highlight it and check the checkbox.

I've tried/think something like:

```
Dim today As String = DateTime.Now
Dim column As DataColumn
For x As Integer = 0 To Me.grdFinYear.Rows.Count - 1
    If grdFinYear.Rows(x).Cells(1).Value.ToString = column.ColumnName Then
        ' lblActiveFinYear.Text = current fin year
        ' colunm.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red
    End If
    '
Next
```

Comment: Is it Web or Winforms? (`datagridview` is Winform's control only)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, as Mych said yoy can use [OnRowDataBound](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.onrowdatabound%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) event. Here is a sample working code:

ASPX markup:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvGrid" runat="server" OnRowDataBound="gvGrid_OnRowDataBound">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="cbYear"/>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Backend code:

```
Public Class WebForm1
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        Dim items = New List(Of GridSomeItem)
        items.Add(New GridSomeItem() With
                  {.StartDate = Date.Now.AddMonths(-2),
                   .EndDate = Date.Now.AddDays(-5)
                  })
        items.Add(New GridSomeItem() With
                  {.StartDate = Date.Now.AddDays(-10),
                   .EndDate = Date.Now.AddDays(10)
                  })
        items.Add(New GridSomeItem() With
                  {.StartDate = Date.Now.AddDays(-20),
                   .EndDate = Date.Now.AddDays(-10)
                  })

        gvGrid.DataSource = items
        gvGrid.DataBind()

    End Sub


    Protected Sub gvGrid_OnRowDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As GridViewRowEventArgs)
        If e.Row.DataItem Is Nothing Then
            Return
        End If

        Dim item As GridSomeItem = e.Row.DataItem
        Dim today As Date = Date.Now

        If today > item.StartDate And today < item.EndDate Then
            e.Row.BackColor = Drawing.Color.Red
            Dim cbYear As CheckBox = e.Row.FindControl("cbYear")

            cbYear.Checked = True

        End If

    End Sub
End Class

Public Class GridSomeItem
    Public Property StartDate As DateTime
    Public Property EndDate As DateTime
End Class
```

It just databound sample items and check are that satisfy condition, and then change color and value for Checkbox

Answer (score 0):

I normally do this using the RowDataBoundEvent this fires as each row is bound. Check that the row bound is a data row and not a header or footer. You can then go to the column you are interested in and if the criteria matches you can change background colour of cell.